# Stars do not change color onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with stars animation on my portfolio. It doesn't change the color. I do not know why this happened, because previously it worked fine.

```js
$(".star").on('click', function() {

  document.getElementById("stars").value = this.id;
  for (let i = 0; i <= this.id; i++) {
    document.getElementById(this.id - i).style.color = "goldenrod";
  }

});
```

```css
.d-inline { display:inline }
.star { cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ratingDiv">
  <div class="star d-inline" id="0">*<i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>

  <div class="star d-inline" id="1">*<i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>

  <div class="star d-inline" id="2">*<i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>

  <div class="star d-inline" id="3">*<i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>

  <div class="star d-inline" id="4">*<i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>
</div>

<br>
<input type="text" id="stars" value="" name="stars" hidden>
</p>
```

https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper09/pen/KKqqGGe

Comment: Please replace your severside code by html code from browser.

Comment: Code replaced to html code from browser

Comment: you can't start an id with number id="2" is wrong,. And this document.getElementById(this.id-i) i think needs the # before this.id (document.getElementById( '#' +  this.id-i))

Comment: @Sfili_81 getElementById doesn't use a *selector* (so no "#")

Comment: Your codepen has jquery twice - the second one will erase any plugins code you have before it.   Can't tell if it makes any difference removing it on your codepen

Comment: I've fixed your snippet (added a `*` for the missing fas-star and a `d-inline` css).  It works fine, **given the code in the question** - but doesn't reset:  `$(".star").css("color", "grey")` to reset - but you'd be better off adding/removing classes than using `.style.color`

Comment: In your codepen, it doesn't *change* colour, because your css line 23 has `.stars { color: #c7d6f6 }` and your js changes the wrapper, not the star itself.   Change that line to `.star { color: #c7d6f6 }` and your codepen works (other than reset as noted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".star").on('click', function(){
  for(let i=0; i<= 4;i++){
    document.getElementById(i).querySelector('.fa-star').style.color = "";
  }
  for(let i=0; i<= this.id;i++){
    document.getElementById(i).querySelector('.fa-star').style.color = "goldenrod";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are changing color of your div element but star is present in  element inside the div change the line inside the loop with this.

```
 document.getElementById(this.id-i).querySelector('.fa-star').style.color = "goldenrod";
```

Comment: Why?  Changing the colour of the div would also change the colour of elements inside it... *unless* they already have their own colour/style, which is not apparent in OPs code (so *may* be the case)

Comment: I think style is in library code as you can see font awesome library is used in above code to insert the stars. fa-star is a class of font awesome icon library.

Comment: Not sure that has anything to do with the colour of the star

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method and contained **click** and **hover**

HTML:

```
<p>
    <p class="username" style="color: #F2AC57;"><%= language.__('Ocena') %></p>
    <div id="ratingDiv">
        <div class="star d-inline" id="0"><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>
        <div class="star d-inline" id="1"><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>
        <div class="star d-inline" id="2"><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>
        <div class="star d-inline" id="3"><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>
        <div class="star d-inline" id="4"><i class="fas fa-star stars"></i></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="stars" value="" name="stars" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".star").on('click', function(){
        if($("#stars").val().length < 1){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            for(let i = 0; i <= id; i++){
                $('#'+i+' .stars').css({color:"goldenrod"});
            }
            $("#stars").val(id);
        }
    }).on("mouseover", function(){
        if($("#stars").val().length < 1){
            $('.stars').css({color:"black"});
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            for(let i = 0; i <= id; i++){
                $('#'+i+' .stars').css({color:"goldenrod"});
            }
        }
    }).on("mouseout", function(){
        if($("#stars").val().length < 1){
            $('.stars').css({color:"black"});
        }
    });
});
```